# Cbind Error " Object not found"

Tags: r

I am trying to run a panel regression in R studio. When I use cbind command

```
x<- cbind(DEX, GRW , Debt, Life)
```

for my independent variables,it returns this error;

> " Error in cbind(DEX, GRW, Debt, Life) : object 'DEX' not found"

However my dependent variable works fine with cbind

as shown below

```
y<- cbind(GDP)
```

Can you help?
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that the variable `DEX` has not been defined anywhere. Can you confirm this?  Try typing `summary(DEX)` ... what do you see?

Comment: When I type summary(DEX), it returns this                                                     > summary(DEX) Error in summary(DEX) : object 'DEX' not found

Comment: I initially copied from the clpboard using this : tino=read.delim("clipboard")                        and got a summary like this;       GDP              DEX              GRW       
 Min.   : 9.120   Min.   :0.0100   Min.   :10.00  
 1st Qu.: 9.515   1st Qu.:0.0400   1st Qu.:10.00  
 Median :10.030   Median :0.0900   Median :22.00  
 Mean   :10.049   Mean   :0.3246   Mean   :21.67  
 3rd Qu.:10.332   3rd Qu.:0.1100   3rd Qu.:33.00  
 Max.   :11.960   Max.   :6.9600   Max.   :33.00  
                  NA's   :118      NA's   :196

Comment: How do I define the variable DEX as well as the rest?@TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined one and only one object when you executed:

```
tino=read.delim("clipboard")
```

The column names of that object are not handled as other objects. If you wnated to create a new object from that dataframe you could do this:

```
x <- with(tino, cbind(DEX, GRW , Debt, Life) )
```

It's possible this might do violence to the contents of x and it would be safer to extract as just those columns of hte dataframe, tino:

```
x <- tino[ , c('DEX', 'GRW' , 'Debt', 'Life')]
```

You should realize that vectors passed to cbind will get turned into matrices (where all their elements have the same class and no other attributes are supported). Matrices have different features than dataframes (which can have multiple column class attributes).